Seeking references for giving geometrical interpretations of electromagnetism and the nuclear forces
From this thread, we have the following comment:

To further blur the line, it is possible to give geometrical interpretations of electromagnetism and the nuclear forces, such that they appear to be very similar to general relativity in their structure (using differential geometry). As such the distinction you are making between force and geometry is far from being so sharp.

Could anyone please provide a reference for where I can read more about this? References that are relatively more accessible would be appreciated.

Can all fundamental forces be fictitious forces?

What level of knowledge do you have of maths and physics?

If you know some calculus and matrices, then "Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics" by Bernard Schutz might help.

Gauge fields, knots, and gravity by Baez and Munian

I particularly enjoyed Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge Theory. This is mostly a mathematics book that develops pretty much all the necessary geometry to formulate gauge theory in a geometrical manner. The book's goal is to formulate the classical (as opposed to quantum) standard model in curved spacetimes from a geometrical perspective.
It also includes discussion of spin structures, for example, which are also geometrical constructions necessary to define spinor fields in a general curved spacetime.
